# ListView Adapter with ToggleButton Filters

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I'm developing an Android app that has a list of 80+ "God" objects, each having a "ClassName" string attribute ("Warrior", "Hunter", "Assassin", etc.).

I am trying to implement ToggleButtons that will filter the list by ClassName. Multiple filters should be allowed at once (example: Checking the "Warrior" and "Hunter" ToggleButtons should display all objects with ClassName "Warrior" OR "Hunter").

So far, I have only been able to filter a list based on one ClassName constraint. Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my main fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,null);

        final ArrayList<God> gods = getGods();

        lv = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
        sv = (SearchView) myView.findViewById(R.id.home_search);
        sv.setQueryHint("Search Gods...");
        mage = (ToggleButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.mage);
        assassin = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.assassin);

        adapter = new GodAdapter(getActivity(), gods);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        mage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    //Include all mages
                }
                else {
                    //Remove all mages

                }
            }
        });

assassin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        //Include all assassins
                    }
                    else {
                        //Remove all assassins

                    }
                }
            });

(...other buttons...)



        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String name = adapter.getItem(position).getName();

                for(int i = 0; i < gods.size(); i++) {
                    if(gods.get(i).getName().equals(name))
                    {
                        Fragment myFragment = new TabFragment();
                        myFragment.setArguments(createGodBundle(gods.get(i)));
                        replaceFragment(myFragment);
                        hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }
```

And here is my GodAdapter:

```
public class GodAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<God> gods;
    ArrayList<God> filterList;
    CustomFilter filter;

    public GodAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<God> gods) {
        this.c = c;
        this.gods = gods;
        this.filterList = gods;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gods.size();
    }

    public God getItem(int position) {
        return gods.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return gods.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.god_selection, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.god_name);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.god_image);
        ImageView pantheon =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pantheon);
        ImageView type =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);

        name.setText(gods.get(position).getName());
        image.setImageResource(gods.get(position).getImage());
        pantheon.setImageResource(gods.get(position).getPantheonIcon());
        type.setImageResource(gods.get(position).getClassIcon());

        return convertView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter == null)
            filter = new CustomFilter();
        return filter;
    }


    //Inner class for filtering
    class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
            {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<God> filters = new ArrayList<God>();

                for(int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                    {
                        God god = new God(filterList.get(i).getName(), filterList.get(i).getTitle(), filterList.get(i).getNameString(), filterList.get(i).getImage(),
                                filterList.get(i).getPantheon(), filterList.get(i).getPantheonIcon(), filterList.get(i).getClassName(), filterList.get(i).getClassIcon(), filterList.get(i).getType(),
                                filterList.get(i).getHealth(), filterList.get(i).getMana(), filterList.get(i).getDamage(), filterList.get(i).getProtPhys(), filterList.get(i).getProtMag(), filterList.get(i).getSpeed(),
                                filterList.get(i).getHp5(), filterList.get(i).getMp5(), filterList.get(i).getAttackSpeed());
                        filters.add(god);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filters.size();
                results.values = filters;
            } else {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            gods = (ArrayList<God>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by keeping a `ArrayList` of all filters in the `Adapter`.

This `ArrayList` would then be your constraint and you can filter the elements by checking if it contains the `God`'s class.

---

Example:

```
public class GodAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    ...
    ArrayList<God> gods;
    ArrayList<God> filteredGods;
    private ArrayList<String> classFilters;

    ...

    public boolean toggleFilter(String class) {
        if (classFilters.contains(class)) {
            classFilters.remove(class);
            return false;
        } else {
            classFilters.add(class);
            return true;
        }
    }

    ...

    class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(classFilters.size() > 0){
                ArrayList<God> filteredList = new ArrayList<God>();

                for(int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++){
                    God god = filterList.get(i);
                    if(classFilters.contains(god.getName().toUpperCase())){
                        filteredList.add(god);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredList.size();
                results.values = filteredList;
            } else {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // IMPORTANT publish the results to a separate list
            filteredGods = (ArrayList<God>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

I would recommend using an `enum` to describe `God` classes instead of `String`s. Explaining why would be too far away from this question, [but you can read about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 1):

What I did for a similar situatios is the following:

I have an array with all the data. 
But to populate the listview I generate a second array by filtering the first one.

For the filter I use a combination of non exclusive keys.

```
public static fianl STATUS_WARRIOR = 1; //binary: 00000001
public static fianl STATUS_HUNTER = 2;  //binary: 00000010
public static fianl STATUS_ASSASIN = 4; //binary: 00000100
```

For each instance of Weapon, it's status will be one of these three.

Your filter creteria based on the toggles can be any combinatios of these three values.

Examples: 
Warrior and Assasin: 00000101
Hunter and Assasin: 00000110

(You just need to `'|'` (or) the active values)

So your toggles will define a number between 0 and 7

For filtering you just need to check the status of the weapon `'&'` (and) the filter creteria. If it is not 0 you include it the array you will pass to the listview.

```
private ArrayList<Weapon> allWeaponsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

// Set all the weapons perhaps in onCreate() inside allWeaponsArrayList.

int statusFromToggles = 0;
statusFromToggles = toggleWarriorOn? statusFromToggles | STATUS_WARRIOR: statusFromToggles ; 
statusFromToggles = toggleHunterOn? statusFromToggles | STATUS_HUNTER: statusFromToggles ; 
statusFromToggles = toggleAssasinOn? statusFromToggles | STATUS_ASSASIN: statusFromToggles ; 

public ArrayList<Weapon> filterWeapons(statusFromToggles){
    ArrayList<Weapon> rtn = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
    for(Weapon weapon : allWeaponsArrayList){
        if(weapon.getStatus() & statusFromToggles){
            rtn.add(weapon);
        }
     }
     return rtn;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't ran the code so it may have some typos. If so let me know and I'll check it. But still you can get the idea.

Comment: I love binary operations. I would extend your answer by using a real `Filter` in a `BaseAdapter`, like in the question. As a constraint, one could pass the filter integer as a String using `Integer.toBinaryString(int i);` and then parse it in the filter using `Integer.parseInt(constraint, 2);`.

Comment: @Barthy, I agree with you about using the Filter, but you can avoid the conversions to binary and handle everything in radix 10.

Comment: but you would still need to parse to and from `String` / `CharSequence`, right?

Comment: Yes, to pass the parameter to the Filter object and then back to use the parameter inside the Filter.